# Is it possible for Clang-format to split multiple variable declarations of the same type over multiple lines?

Tags: java, formatting, checkstyle, pmd, clang-format

I'm using clang-format to prettify my Java code on top of the Google formatter.

It's mostly fine but it doesn't allow multiple declarations over multiple lines.

It packs the variable declarations

`String one, two, three;`

into a single line whereas I'd want them aligned vertically over three lines.

Like so:

```
String one, 
       two,
       three;
```

( I can't get the alignment right in SO).

My clang-format configuration file is as follows:

```
Language:        Java
# BasedOnStyle:  Google
AccessModifierOffset: -1
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands:   true
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
#AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BraceWrapping:   
  AfterClass:      false
  AfterControlStatement: false
  AfterEnum:       false
  AfterFunction:   false
  AfterNamespace:  false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct:     false
  AfterUnion:      false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  BeforeCatch:     false
  BeforeElse:      false
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: NonAssignment
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: true
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:     80
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: true
DisableFormat:   false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:   
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IncludeBlocks:   Preserve
IncludeCategories: 
  - Regex:           '^<ext/.*\.h>'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '^<.*\.h>'
    Priority:        1
  - Regex:           '^<.*'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        3
IncludeIsMainRegex: '([-_](test|unittest))?$'
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentWidth:     2
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Never
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 1
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 200
PointerAlignment: Left
RawStringFormats: 
  - Language:        Cpp
    Delimiters:      
      - cc
      - CC
      - cpp
      - Cpp
      - CPP
      - 'c++'
      - 'C++'
    CanonicalDelimiter: ''
    BasedOnStyle:    google
  - Language:        TextProto
    Delimiters:      
      - pb
      - PB
      - proto
      - PROTO
    EnclosingFunctions: 
      - EqualsProto
      - EquivToProto
      - PARSE_PARTIAL_TEXT_PROTO
      - PARSE_TEST_PROTO
      - PARSE_TEXT_PROTO
      - ParseTextOrDie
      - ParseTextProtoOrDie
    CanonicalDelimiter: ''
    BasedOnStyle:    google
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    true
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 2
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Auto
StatementMacros: 
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth:        2
UseTab:          Never
...
```

The above can also be viewed [here](https://github.com/Fernal73/LearnJava/blob/master/.clang-format).
The file on GitHub can change.

I'm using version 8 of Clang-format. I don't have access to Version 9 on Termux and Arch Linux on Termux.

The above breaks Checkstyle and PMD rules regarding multiple variable declarations, specifically [MultipleVariableDeclarations](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/coding/MultipleVariableDeclarationsCheck.html)  and [OneDeclarationPerLine](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_java_bestpractices.html#onedeclarationperline) respectively.

A workaround would be to format as above and then mark that section of the code with // clang-format off and // clang-format on so that the formatting is undisturbed. It's a workaround and it does pollute the source.

The other options would be to use NOPMD or Checkstyle Suppressions either via comments or checkstyle annotations.

Comment: If you want declarations on three lines, why not just use three separate declarations?

Comment: I'm more interested in whether clang-format can fix this. I can disable the PMD and Checkstyle rules if needed. That'll make that bugbear go away too. I was wondering if clang-format can do exactly what Google Java Format does.

Comment: I do want it over three lines but not by declaring String thrice. Just once.

Comment: Is this going to be a problem while handling other languages namely C, C++ with reference to pointer and address variables?